# z-index not working for HTML5 video

Tags: css, html, html5-video, z-index

I have a problem with my site as z-index kind of works but it doesn't and I have not found an answer that fits my needs on the internet.

```css
.Mwrapper 
    {
        z-index: 2;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0%;
        margin-top: 120em;
    }

    .Msliding-background 
    {
        z-index: 2;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .Mhider
    {
        z-index: 2;
        height: 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.1),  rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,1));
    }
    .Mvid
    {
        z-index: -2;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 25em;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .Mvid video
    {
        position: relative;
        z-index: -1;
        height: 720px;
        width: 1280px;
    }

    .Mvideo
    {
        bottom: 724px;
        left: 120px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
        height: 725px;
        width: 1280px;
        background: radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.6), rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,1));
    }
```

```html
 <div id="Mfog" class="Mwrapper"><div class="Msliding-background"><div class="Mhider"></div> </div></div>
    
    <nav class="Mvid">
        <video id="video">
           <source src="demo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="Mvideo" onclick="audioPause()"></div>
    </nav>
```

It works in the sense that Mvideo appears above Mvid video but Mwrapper does not appear above Mvid.

All help appreciated :)

Comment: Tip : `z-index` must be in a `relative/absolute` or `fixed` element and can't be negative. :-)

Comment: z-index can be negative, that's perfectly acceptable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, .Mwrapper doesn't even appear on your screen.
First of all, you need to define a left: value for a fixed item, and your margin-top is pushing it entirely off screen.

Try:

```
.Mwrapper 
{
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0%;
    left:0;
}
```

With this code, .Mwrapper won't be visible - but as soon as you put content inside it, you'll se it appear.

Here it is with fixed width, so it appears even when empty of content:

```
.Mwrapper 
{
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100vw;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
}

.Msliding-background 
{
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: red;
    width:calc(100vw - 200px);
    margin:auto;
    height:30px; 
}
```

You'll see that z-index is working exactly like it's supposed to:

https://jsfiddle.net/ZheerH/a444bqLf/2/